# Updating PostgreSQL array column - avoiding duplicate values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `integer[]` column and I want to update this column, but avoid having duplicate entries in the array.

Example: First `[123]` is the value. 
Next time I want to add `234`. Here `array_append()` works fine. But it shouldn't allow adding `123` again.

So my question: How can I append a value to an array only if that item is not present yet in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
UPDATE "my_table"
   SET "int_array" = array_append("int_array", :element_to_insert)
 WHERE :some_filters
   AND :element_to_insert <> ALL ("int_array")
```

More possibilities:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-comparisons.html

Comment: Dosnt this flush and update only new entries every time? Does it keep the old entries?

Comment: This updates *only*, when the array doesn't contain the element you want to append. array contains element = `element = ANY (array)` - array does not contain element = `element <> ALL (array)`

Answer (score 4):

For integer arrays, you can [use the `intarray` extension's `uniq` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html):

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

UPDATE thetable SET thecol = uniq(array_append(thecol, 32)) WHERE ...
```